# Which video card for a 1680x1050 resolution?

Tags: video, graphics

i've a 22" monitor, i'm using Ubuntu 10.10. 
My video card is a Radeon X1300 and i've poor performance at that resolution. 
If i decrease resolution to 1280x1024 for example, i can use netbeans, monodevelop etc. without problem.

So i'm asking: which agp video card can i buy to have GOOD performance with Ubuntu at high resolution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately AGP is a dated technology and its a bit difficult to find good agp cards in the markets now. AtI needs to be commended because they have R600/R700 Cards which still support the agp specification. Depending on your budget, you can go with either the Radeon 3650, 3850 or 4650. Even 3650 will not have a problem handling your resolution. Plus using the proprietary fglrx driver, cards would run very fine.

Comment: I am very happy with my 3650 :)